# Having problems generating random monsters using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to help my lad learn Python, so am first learning it myself! Please bear with, as I'm just 2 days in to this fun, but slightly overwhelming journey.

I've made good progress via lots of helpful video's from various folk, but am stuck on trying to get random monsters to generate with random attributes. Any guidance would be very much appreciated,

Thanks,

Ian

```
import cmd
import random

# Monster Setup

class monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = ""
        self.character = ""
        self.hp = ""
        self.mp = ""
        self.xp = ""
        self.gc = "" #gold coins
        self.location = ""
        self.dead = False
   
myMonster = monster()

class kobold(monster):
    def __init__(self):
        #super calls the parent class (monster) in this case
        super().__init__
        self.type = 'kobold'
        self.hp = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.mp = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.gc = random.randint(50, 100)
        self.xp = random.randint(200, 300)
koboldMonster = kobold()

def kobold():
    return myMonster()

class goblin(monster):
    def __init__(self):
        #super calls the parent class (monster) in this case
        super().__init__
        self.type = 'goblin'
        self.hp = random.randint(40, 80)
        self.mp = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.gc = random.randint(100, 200)
        self.xp = random.randint(400, 600)
goblinMonster = goblin()
#print('A Goblin appeared!',  'Will you fight or run?\n')

(common_monsters) = [goblin, kobold]

def goblin():
    return myMonster()

def call_monster():
    monster_selection = random.choice(common_monsters)
    monster_selected = monster_selection()

call_monster()
```

Comment: You can't have a class called `goblin` and a function called `goblin`.  The second will erase the first.  Eliminate those functions, and I suspect your code will work.  `common_monsters` will contain the class objects, and `call_monster` will create an instance of the chosen one.

Comment: also you should name classes Goblin, Monster etc. and do not use type as variable since its buil-in name. Use type_ if you must. Also in goblin kobold etc you are calling an object wich is not callable.

Comment: Your code creates a monster object, but you don't output anything anywhere so nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code, modified so it works.  You don't need those functions, and you don't want the `myMonster` thing in the first place.  Just let the random choice thing pick one of the existing classes, and return an instance of it.

Also note that you were not calling the parent class constructor.  You were missing the `()` at the end to actually call the function.

```
import random

# Monster Setup

class monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = ""
        self.character = ""
        self.hp = ""
        self.mp = ""
        self.xp = ""
        self.gc = "" #gold coins
        self.location = ""
        self.dead = False
   
class kobold(monster):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.type = 'kobold'
        self.hp = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.mp = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.gc = random.randint(50, 100)
        self.xp = random.randint(200, 300)

class goblin(monster):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.type = 'goblin'
        self.hp = random.randint(40, 80)
        self.mp = random.randint(20, 40)
        self.gc = random.randint(100, 200)
        self.xp = random.randint(400, 600)

common_monsters = [goblin, kobold]

def call_monster():
    monster_selection = random.choice(common_monsters)
    monster_selected = monster_selection()
    return monster_selected

print(call_monster())
```

You could even simplify the final function to:

```
def call_monster():
    return random.choice(common_monsters)()
```

I'd like to add a philosophical comment, for your future design meetings.  It seems natural to create subclasses like `kobold` and `goblin`, but in reality you wouldn't want that kind of thing hard-coded in your code.  You're going to want a configuration file or a database that describes each of the monster types you want to create.  Thus, your eventual design will probably just have a generic `Monster` class, and the attributes will be loaded from the database based on the monster type.

What you're doing is a great experiment for learning about classes and inheritance, but as you get farther along, you'll probably toss this and go more generic.

### FOLLOWUP

OK, here's a slight modification that shows how to create a phalanx of monsters, and then display them one by one.  The middle part is the same, so I haven't included it.

```
import random

# Monster Setup

class monster:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = ""
        self.character = ""
        self.hp = ""
        self.mp = ""
        self.xp = ""
        self.gc = "" #gold coins
        self.location = ""
        self.dead = False
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<monster: type {self.type}, hp {self.hp}, mp {self.mp}, gc {self.gc}, xp {self.xp}>"
...
def create_monster():
    return random.choice(common_monsters)()

# Create 8 random monsters.

monsters = [create_monster() for _ in range(8)]

# List them all.

for bad in monsters:
    print( bad )
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've tried your code which returns: <__main__.goblin object at 0x0000024A2660BDF0>. Is that correct? I was hoping to be able to then use the randomly chosen monster to fight the player. When I add this code to the rest of the script it seems to do nothing. I thought I could simply call it by typing call_monster() - am I wrong? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that says it created a `goblin` object.  If you run it again, you'll probably get a `kobold`.  You can add a `__repr__` method to those to have them print more useful information, if you want.  Yes, you can just do `call_monster`, but that creates an object, and you have to put the object somewhere if you want it to live.  You'll probably have a list called `monsters` to hold the collection.

Comment: So I have a list called [common monsters] that goblin is in. How would I associate the two? I manged to get the fighting mechanics working when I hard coded the goblin, but I am struggling to do the same from a list. Apologies if I'm struggling to join the dots here.

Comment: `common_monsters` has the monster TYPES.  It doesn't contain any monster instances.  For that, you need another list.  See the mods above.